# Solution to get static script elements after dynamically appended elements

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Within a web application I'm working on, in order to achieve the "app feel" - content being retrieved in the background instead of foreground -  I'm using the appendChild() and removeChild() Javascript methods to append and remove elements as necessary. Doing so however, creates a small interference. Like as should be done, I place my script elements right before the closing body tag. But the appendChild() method (obviously as intended) appends child elements at the end, so some of the functions within the (now) above script tags process before its corresponding element even exists in the DOM.

So my question being, what should I do? I was thinking of simply placing a wrapper div inside of the body so I can keep the script tags at the end of the body. But is this the best solution? Is there anything easier, or maybe something to append elements into certain spots within the DOM?

Comment: What I usually do is tag a div element with an id then use promises for async data retrieval and specify a few callbacks to trigger rendering of new elements. For certain spots beyond the initial div tag ill use either mustache is or underscore for templating sections. It all really depends on the context, content and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you append stuff after your script tags or before them. I believe you're actually looking for event delegation, could you post a simple example reproducing your problem?

Comment: I'm not actually trying to append elements after the script tags. It just happened to be the functionality of appendChild() when I learned about the method. After a little digging, the insertBefore() method MIGHT be what I'm looking for. If not, I'll see about posting a "simple" example.

Comment: Yep, the insertBefore() method was just what I was looking for. Also found out about the defer attribute which may come in handy sooner or later.

Comment: Okay then, sounds like I didn't understand the problem.